# Customize method in BLC

Tags: acumatica

I need to modify the method below.  I want to allow the unapplied balance for payments to go negative.  I have a process to bring in payments and add all the invoices to the payment.  The users will then add any credit memos required to balance the payment.  I know what code needs to change but it is in the middle of the method.  I can override the method, but I am not sure where to invoke the base handler.  I have been reviewing T300, but it is not clicking in my brain.  Should I invoke the base first and then recode the last few lines in my extension?

```
    private void ARAdjust_AdjdRefNbr_FieldUpdated<T>(PXResult<T, CurrencyInfo> res, ARAdjust adj)
        where T : ARRegister, IInvoice, new()
    {
        CurrencyInfo info_copy = PXCache<CurrencyInfo>.CreateCopy((CurrencyInfo)res);
        info_copy.CuryInfoID = null;
        info_copy = (CurrencyInfo)currencyinfo.Cache.Insert(info_copy);
        T invoice = (T)res;

        //currencyinfo.Cache.SetValueExt<CurrencyInfo.curyEffDate>(info_copy, Document.Current.DocDate);
        info_copy.SetCuryEffDate(currencyinfo.Cache, Document.Current.DocDate);

        adj.CustomerID = Document.Current.CustomerID;
        adj.AdjgDocDate = Document.Current.AdjDate;
        adj.AdjgCuryInfoID = Document.Current.CuryInfoID;
        adj.AdjdCustomerID = invoice.CustomerID;
        adj.AdjdCuryInfoID = info_copy.CuryInfoID;
        adj.AdjdOrigCuryInfoID = invoice.CuryInfoID;
        adj.AdjdBranchID = invoice.BranchID;
        adj.AdjdARAcct = invoice.ARAccountID;
        adj.AdjdARSub = invoice.ARSubID;
        adj.AdjdDocDate = invoice.DocDate;
        adj.AdjdFinPeriodID = invoice.FinPeriodID;
        adj.AdjdHasPPDTaxes = invoice.HasPPDTaxes;
        adj.Released = false;
        adj.PendingPPD = false;

        CalcBalances<T>(adj, invoice, false);

        decimal? CuryApplAmt = adj.CuryDocBal - adj.CuryDiscBal;
        decimal? CuryApplDiscAmt = adj.CuryDiscBal;
        decimal? CuryUnappliedBal = Document.Current.CuryUnappliedBal;

//=======================================================================
// I need to add this compare to stop the existing Acumatica logic from
// limiting the application amount to the amount of the unapplied balance 
// for payments generated by my EDI import.  See comment below
//
        if (Document.Current != null && Document.Current.docDesc.Substring(0, 4) == "EDI:")
            return;
//======================================================================

        if (adj.CuryDiscBal >= 0m && adj.CuryDocBal - adj.CuryDiscBal <= 0m)
        {
            //no amount suggestion is possible
            return;
        }

        if (Document.Current != null && adj.AdjgBalSign < 0m)
        {
            if (CuryUnappliedBal < 0m)
            {
                CuryApplAmt = Math.Min((decimal)CuryApplAmt, Math.Abs((decimal)CuryUnappliedBal));
            }
        }
//=================================================================
// This code is part of original Acumatica and will not apply more to an 
// invoice than is available in the payment amount.  It will only apply
// the minimum of document amount or unapplied balance.
//
        else if (Document.Current != null && CuryUnappliedBal > 0m && adj.AdjgBalSign > 0m)
        {
            CuryApplAmt = Math.Min((decimal)CuryApplAmt, (decimal)CuryUnappliedBal);
//=========================================================================
            if (CuryApplAmt + CuryApplDiscAmt < adj.CuryDocBal)
            {
                CuryApplDiscAmt = 0m;
            }
        }
        else if (Document.Current != null && CuryUnappliedBal <= 0m && ((ARPayment)Document.Current).CuryOrigDocAmt > 0)
        {
            CuryApplAmt = 0m;
            CuryApplDiscAmt = 0m;
        }

        adj.CuryAdjgAmt = CuryApplAmt;
        adj.CuryAdjgDiscAmt = CuryApplDiscAmt;
        adj.CuryAdjgPPDAmt = CuryApplDiscAmt;
        adj.CuryAdjgWOAmt = 0m;

        CalcBalances<T>(adj, invoice, true);
    }
```

Comment: Jerry, can you please tell a bit more. You want to modify method in your graph, or to override it in graph extension? In any case, which part of the code, you've showed prevents balances from going negative?

Comment: The code right after the comment I put in where it tests CuryUnappliedBal and AdjgBalSign and applies the minimum of the invoice amount or unapplied amount. I need to change that to always use the invoice amount. After looking at it further I was thinking I could extend the graph, invoke the base handler, and then modify the application amount and call calculate balances again.  I'm just not quite sure of the best way.

Comment: you modify your own code, or you want to override basic functionality?

Comment: I need to override basic functionality.  The code above is from ARPaymentEntry.  It is the ARAdjust_AdjdRefNbr_FieldUpdated method.  I need to add the test indicated in the first comment block to exit the method and stop the code in the second comment block from limiting the application amount.

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution that appears to work, but please comment on it if you see a problem.  After walking through the base code, I determined what fields would need to be changed to always pay the remaining invoice balance. My only issue (I think) is that I could not call the CalcBalances method in the ARPaymentEntry graph from my extension. I was able to call the public PaymentEntry.CalcBalances method so I hope that is ok.  I also added an exception to the payment if it is not on hold and not in balance.  Please comment on anything that does not look correct.

```
using PX.Data;
using PX.Objects.CM;

namespace PX.Objects.AR
{
    public class ARPaymentEntry_Extension : PXGraphExtension<ARPaymentEntry>
    {
        #region Event Handlers
        protected void ARPayment_RowUpdated(PXCache sender, PXRowUpdatedEventArgs e,
            PXRowUpdated InvokeBaseHandler)
        {
            if (InvokeBaseHandler != null)
                InvokeBaseHandler(sender, e);
            ARPayment payment = (ARPayment)e.Row;
            if (payment.OpenDoc == true && payment.Hold != true)
            {
                if ((payment.CuryUnappliedBal != 0m) && !(bool)payment.Hold)
                {
                    sender.RaiseExceptionHandling<ARPayment.curyOrigDocAmt>(payment, 
                        payment.CuryOrigDocAmt, 
                        new PXSetPropertyException(Messages.DocumentOutOfBalance));
                }
                else
                {
                    sender.RaiseExceptionHandling<ARPayment.curyOrigDocAmt>
                        (payment, null, null);
                }
            }
        }

        protected void ARAdjust_AdjdRefNbr_FieldUpdated(PXCache cache, 
            PXFieldUpdatedEventArgs e, PXFieldUpdated InvokeBaseHandler)
        {
            if (InvokeBaseHandler != null)
                InvokeBaseHandler(cache, e);

            ARAdjust adj = (ARAdjust)e.Row;

            foreach (PXResult<ARInvoice, CurrencyInfo> res in
                Base.ARInvoice_DocType_RefNbr.Select(adj.AdjdDocType, adj.AdjdRefNbr))
            {
                ARInvoice invoice = (ARInvoice)res;
                CurrencyInfo curInfo = (CurrencyInfo)res;
                if (Base.Document.Current != null && 
                    Base.Document.Current.DocDesc.Substring(0, 4) == "EDI:")
                {
                    adj.CuryAdjgAmt = invoice.CuryOrigDocAmt;
                    PaymentEntry.CalcBalances<ARInvoice, ARAdjust>
                        (Base.CurrencyInfo_CuryInfoID, adj.AdjdCuryInfoID, 
                             Base.Document.Current.DocDate, invoice, adj);
                }
            }
        }
        #endregion
    }
}
```